# Loading excel files in structures

Tags: excel, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-struct

I am working on a small project which requires huge amount of data to be imported into matlab for further processing. I have currently 15 excel files and each file has 8 sheets. What I want is to make a parent structure in which I want load each excel file as a structure e.g.

```
parentstructure.filename.value{}
```

Where  parentstructure is a main structure and filename is an excel file which is an another structure in parent structure and each excel file has a 8 sheets in a cell.

I have written a small code to read data into matlab. The code is as follows

```
srcdir = '';  %%% where all the files are placed
srcfiles = dir(fullfile(srcdir, '*.xls'));

for p = 1:numel(srcfiles)

    filename = fullfile(srcdir, srcfiles(p).name);
    [~,sheets] = xlsfinfo(srcfiles(p).name);

    for i = 1:8
        Sheet = char(sheets(1,i)) ;
        value{p,i} = xlsread(filename,Sheet);

    end
end
```

This code works fine and loads the data into matlab but not in the structrue form I wanted. I tried several other combinations and adjustments but getting errors. Any help or guuide will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the code that you've postsed, you haven't actually created the `struct`. You do this using the `struct` keyword. Then, in order to assign each file to a `filename` field, you'll want to use `genvarname` (or `matlab.lang.makeValidName`) to convert the filename to a valid field name and assign the struct to this.

```
% Initialize Parent Structure
parentStructure = struct();

srcdir = '';  %%% where all the files are placed
srcfiles = dir(fullfile(srcdir, '*.xls'));

% Sort the files by numbers in their names
numbers = regexp({srcfiles.name}, '\d+', 'match');
numbers = str2double(cat(1, numbers{:}));
[~, sortind] = sort(numbers);
srcfiles = srcfiles(sortind);

for p = 1:numel(srcfiles)

    % Convert filename to a valid field name
    fieldname = matlab.lab.makeValidName(srcfiles(p).name);

    filename = fullfile(srcdir, srcfiles(p).name);
    [~,sheets] = xlsfinfo(filename);

    value = cell(1,8);

    for k = 1:8
        Sheet = char(sheets(1,k)) ;
        value{k} = xlsread(filename,Sheet);
    end

    % Now assign this struct of sheets to your parentStructure
    parentStructure.(fieldname) = value;
end
```

Comment: it worked and data is loaded.But now the problem is files are not loaded in sequence. This is because the file names starts as a numeric number e.g. 1.xls,2.xls and so on. But in a structure matlab is arranging is way like 1.xls,10.xls,11.xls... 2.xls,3.xls..... Is there any way to make matlab to read files in sequence and dont adjust them?. This is important as rest of my code depends on this.

Comment: @Muhammad I have added the sorting part to the code above